# How to specify Encoder when mapping a Spark Dataset from one type to another?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Spark dataset of the following type:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Array[Double]]
```

I want to map the array to a Vector so that I can use it as the input dataset for ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(...). So I try to do something like this:

```
val featureVectors = vectors.map(r => Vectors.dense(r))
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

I guess I need to specify an encoder for the map operation, but I struggle with finding a way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need the encoder to be available as implicit evidence:

```
def map[U : Encoder](func: T => U): Dataset[U]
```

breaks down to:

```
def map[U](func: T => U)(implicit evidence$1: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

So, you need to pass it in or have it available implicitly.

That said, I do not believe that Vector is supported as of yet, so you might have to drop to a DataFrame.

Comment: Yeah, I actually got that far from the docs. But I didn't understand how to do it in practice. Also, if Vector is not supported, how come it is documented as the input to the ml.clustering.kmeans implementation? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-clustering.html